# New AMP HTML tags and indexing by search engines

Tags: indexing, googlebot, google-crawlers, amp-html

AMP HTML comes with some new html tags which are transformed into normal elements by javascript… such as

```
<div>
  <amp-img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
  </amp-img>
</div>
```

(example from documentation)

**But how can be such image indexed by google bot, and another search engines?**

Will Googlebot indexing `amp-img` as normal image?

What about others… Bing, Yahoo, … ?

Or for image indexing we should use some polyfills like:

```
<div>
  <amp-img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
  </amp-img>
  <noscript>
    <img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
  </noscript>
</div>
```

or

```
<div>
  <amp-img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
    <noscript>
        <img width=500 height=500 src="https://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
    </noscript>
  </amp-img>
</div>
```

?

I can't find anything about this in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Your amp pages should be only for platforms which look for `<link rel=amphtml/>`, you should be pointing normal users and normal search engines to your normal/non-amp page.  That non-amp page will reference the AMP version in `<link rel=amphtml/>` and it seems like a perfectly realistic expectation that any bot following that link will know how to read amp HTML.

I expect that the worst thing you can do is try to make your AMP page look more like a standard HTML document by adding things like images and making it an invalid AMP document, I believe that invalid AMP HTML pages aren't expected to appear in Google's search results and I wouldn't be surprised if that's a behaviour which will be implemented by the different companies rolling out AMP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll be able to find a definite answer in the documentation (or anywhere else), so I'll just give you my best guess. According to [`a`](http://www.amazeemetrics.com/en/blog/accelerated-mobile-pages-make-the-mobile-web-faster) [`few`](http://www.webpronews.com/google-announces-open-source-accelerated-mobile-pages-project-2015-10/) [`sources`](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/191-htmlcss/9055-google-speeds-up-mobile-html-with-amp-.html), AMP HTML won't be affecting search results (which to me implies that these pages are indexed the same way as non-AMP pages).

Also, the [documentation](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/builtins/amp-img.md) for the amp-img tag says that it is a "runtime-managed replacement for the HTML `img` tag" and that it will have attributes similar to the regular `img` tag (including a `srcset` attribute, where the behavior will be polyfilled if not natively supported). Based on this information, I believe that `amp-img` and the other replacement tags will be indexed the same way the regular tags are.